# DateTime ToLocalTime() DisplayFor realisation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I want to show DateTime data in local time in my ASPNET.Core project.
Usually I had this code to do this:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(item.Date.ToLocalTime(), "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")</td>
```

but this way of writing seems to be inconvenient and different from other fields representation (as regularly following representation used:
'@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ExecutionTime)`)

So my idea is to improve DisplayFor method for this need to make it look the following way:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date)</td>
```

and it could convert DateTime inside.

Did anybody had same need and maybe resolved it somehow?

It is also important to stick to DisplayFor method in order to keep the code unvaried. Any help would be highly appreciated)

Comment: What about setting the formart of model property?Such as `[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]`.

Comment: That`s what I`m using, but I need to make my data LocalTime one. Unfortunately the attribute doesn`t have this option. I thought overriding it, but it is static so it won`t work. Also tried to do it via extension, but keeping same name doesn`t allow me to use it as Microsoft implementation is considered to be more preferable for visual studio.